# How to get string without code ascii

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

About above picture I set the first variable in machine with word "hello"
 (`SerialPort.Write()`)

> 02 "0A" 14 "01hello" 03

*Image* *****

Then I request the first variable in machine (`SerialPort.ReadExisting()`)

> 02 "0B01" 03

*Image* *****

The output is

> ૯୫1A૯୫01hello૯୫૯୫2A૯୫01hello૯୫ ૯୫3A૯୫01hello૯୫ ....

If I click the button request, number before A, always change and sequence until the number 9

How to get string desired result is just hello?

***** *I cannot post the picture because I need at least 10 reputation to post image.*

Some code I use

```
Private Sub readMemoryButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles readMemoryButton.Click
    'copy
    'Received.AppendText("TX" & vbCrLf)        ' Switch to a new line after every transmission
    'SpaceCount = 0
    Dim TextString As String
    Dim TXArray(2047) As Byte
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Integer = 0
    Dim Ascii As Boolean = False
    Dim Quote As Boolean = False
    Dim Temp As Boolean
    Dim Second As Boolean = False
    Dim TXByte As Byte = 0
    Dim CharByte As Byte
    If COMPort.IsOpen Then
        TextString = Received.Text
        For I = 0 To TextString.Length - 1
            CharByte = Asc(TextString.Chars(I))
            If CharByte = 34 Then ' If " Then
                Temp = Ascii
                Ascii = Ascii Or Quote
                Quote = Not (Temp And Quote)
            Else
                Ascii = Ascii Xor Quote
                Quote = False
            End If
            If Not Quote Then
                If Ascii Then
                    TXArray(J) = CharByte
                    J = J + 1
                Else
                    If (CharByte <> 32) And (CharByte <> 10) And (CharByte <> 13) Then ' Skip spaces, LF and CR
                        CharByte = (CharByte - 48) And 31 ' And 31 makes it case insensitive
                        If CharByte > 16 Then
                            CharByte = CharByte - 7
                        End If
                        If Second Then
                            TXArray(J) = TXByte + CharByte
                            Second = False
                            J = J + 1
                        Else
                            TXByte = CharByte << 4
                            Second = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Try
            COMPort.Write(TXArray, 0, J)
            Dim vLabelMemory As String = COMPort.ReadExisting()
            labelMemory.Text = vLabelMemory
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & "  Check CTS signal or set Flow Control to None.")
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("COM port is closed. Please select a COM port")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If only there was an easy way to format code as code here.

Comment: @Agus Highlight your code and press ctrl+k to format your code.

Comment: Sory for that code,i'm posting by phone. Thanks for your advise,
As soon as possible I change the format code, because I run on the way

Comment: There's no way you wrote the comments in your code example. So maybe look at the original source of your code for more explanation? A quick web search returns [this from 2007](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d04b7dfb-2b15-4a98-8f3e-533dc951c3c9/code-understanding?forum=vblanguage) which may help. And what about [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?846677-How-to-Parse-received-data&p=5165075) did you not understand?